# CSP: Relative img src on https site tries to link to http image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy, rails-activestorage

I have a site on HTTPS and i am linking to images with relative links. I am generating the link with a rails helper

```
 <%= image_tag url_for(screenshot.attachment) %>
```

Which produces an image tag like

```
<img src="/rails/blobs/myimage.jpg"/>
```

Although the site is on HTTPS and i am using a relative path, i get the following CSP error

```
Refused to load the image 'http://example.com/rails/blobs/myimage.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22screenshot.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27screenshot.jpg' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https: data:".
```

I don't understand why it is trying to load the image from HTTP.

Comment: it doesn't seems to be a rails problem, if you set the path as static like in the example, it will be resolved by the browser I think. if you use img_tag, that wouldn't happen. if you can't change it to img_tag, try with this, put double slash at the beggining of the the path and see if it works. I will create the answer if it works. something like <img src="//rails/blobs/myimage.jpg"/>

Comment: I am using an image tag, updated my question above. The static is just showing what HTML is produced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your nginx config have to do https forwarding. Then this problem will take care.

Answer (score 0):

Add only_path and set it to false.

```
url_for(screenshot.attachment, :only_path => false)
```

By default it's on false, but to be sure, add it to your helper and see how it works.

If it doesn't help, you can create the complete url like

```
request.host + url_for(screenshot.attachment)
```